Honeybadger warning: unable to send event; reached max queue size of 59547
We are observing this warning from Honeybadger on Ruby on rails service: unable to send event; reached max queue size of 59547.
Current Gem version used:
gem "honeybadger", "~> 5.11"
Ruby version:
3.3.1
Also we have observed that errors from the front end are reported but backend errors are not reported sometimes.
Has anyone observed similar warnings? How can we resolve this?

For the queue size warning, upgrade to the latest version of the gem.
For the backend errors not being reported, check to make sure the API key is present in your backend environment. If that doesn't do the trick, then follow the rest of the suggestions in the troubleshooting guide.
Feel free to contact support if those suggestions don't work for you.

It might be worth noting that you're Honeybadger's co-founder ;)
